# Hashtable/Dictionary but with key composed of multiple values?

Tags: .net, dictionary, hashtable

Lets say I have an object that has stringProp1, stringProp2.  I wish to store each combination of stringProp1, stringProp2 in a Dictionary.  Initially I was storing the key as key = stringProp1+stringProp2 but this can actually cause a bug depending on the 2 values.  Is the best solution for this problem to create a custom dictionary class or is there a better way using built-in .NET classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what data structure you use as the key as long as the key holds the necessary information for a comparer to properly compare/hash.

You can even use your objects as keys in the dictionary and compare on any field you like with an appropriate `EqualityComparer` implementation. This one compares on two string properties using ordinal comparison:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string StringProp1 { get; set; }
    public string StringProp2 { get; set; }
    public MyObject(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        StringProp1 = prop1;
        StringProp2 = prop2;
    }
}

class MyObjectComparerS1S2 : EqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    //Change this if you need e.g. case insensitivity or 
    //culture-specific comparisons
    static StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.Ordinal;

    public override bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return 
            comparer.Equals(x.StringProp1, y.StringProp1) &&
            comparer.Equals(x.StringProp2, y.StringProp2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        //Uncomment this if running in a checked context
        //Copycat of Jon Skeet's string hash combining
        //unchecked
        //{
            return 
                (527 + comparer.GetHashCode(obj.StringProp1)) * 31 +
                comparer.GetHashCode(obj.StringProp2);
        //}
    }

    public static readonly MyObjectComparerS1S2 Instance = 
        new MyObjectComparerS1S2();

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<MyObject, MyObject> dict = 
        new Dictionary<MyObject, MyObject>(MyObjectComparerS1S2.Instance);
    MyObject obj = new MyObject("apple", "plum");
    dict.Add(obj, obj);
    MyObject search = new MyObject("apple", "plum");
    MyObject result = dict[search];
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", result.StringProp1, result.StringProp2);
}
```

You can search for an object by creating a dummy one, filling in the string keys and using the dummy as the key for the lookup.
If you do not like this idea, or it is not feasible, just do as [@Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366792/hashtable-dictionary-but-with-key-composed-of-multiple-values/2366902#2366902) said and extract the keys in a struct or class. In this case, modify the comparer to derive from `EqualityComparer<MyKeyStructOrClass>`.

Note that I've used [Jon Skeet's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079192/is-it-possible-to-combine-hash-codes-for-private-members-to-generate-a-new-hash-c/1079203#1079203) for combining string hashes. It might be better than the [XOR method found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). If you feel that it is steel inadequate, feel free to treat the strings with another hash implementation - [Hsieh](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html), [Murmur](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/), [Bob Jenkin's](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/), or whatever you believe in. Here is a [nice page about hash functions](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/) that actually has some C# code as well.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4, you can use a `System.Tuple` as a key.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>, int>();
dict.Add(Tuple.Create("foo","bar"), 1);
```

Comment: You could also reference FSharp.Core if you wanted to use this in earlier versions of .NET

Comment: You can also getaway with using keyvaluepair in .Net 3.5 as new dictionary<keyvaluepair<string,string>>. But looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a struct with 2 strings as a key? This would be the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you populate the dictionary and what you do with it, it's possible to use an anonymous type as the key.  For example if you have a class `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And if you had a sequence of these, an `IEnumerable<Person>`, and wanted to create a dictionary that maps names to ages, you can write:

```
var personDictionary = people.ToDictionary(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName });
```

This gives you a dictionary with the first name and last name as the key, and stores the entire `Person` as the value.  You can later look up a key with:

```
personDictionary.TryGetValue(new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
    out person);
```

This won't help help you much if you're trying to pass the dictionary between different classes or even methods, it becomes hard to manage, but for doing some quick data processing in a single method, it works great.  In fact, it's quite common to use anonymous classes as the key for the `GroupBy` extension method or the `group by` query comprehension syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a delimiter in there, if there is a character that won't turn up in either string.

eg

```
stringProp1 + "|" + stringProp2
```

If there isn't then I'd recommend `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MyValueType>>` as in

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MyValueType>>();
// .... Do stuff
if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(stringProp1))
    dictionary.Add(stringProp1, new Dictionary<string, MyValueType>());
dictionary[stringProp1][stringProp2] = myValue;
```

Comment: This won't work. How about the pair "blah|","blah" and the pair "blah","|blah". You need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MD5 algorithm to produce a value for each string and then sum up the two values. The result is the key.
.NET provide the class MD5CryptoServiceProvider in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace. That class contains the method ComputeHash to compute the hash value.

Comment: This is not reliable. If the strings are random, the probability 1/2^128 is that the md5 hashes will collide. And this is going to be rather slow.